# Parametized Postgres Query with IN clause

Tags: postgresql, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I have a query param of type array to collect IDs to query from a postgres table. I think I have built everything out appropriately, but the query fails with `ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"`

The logs are:

```
SELECT
  professional_leads.first_name
  , professional_leads.last_name
  , professional_leads.email
  , professional_leads.phone_number
  , professional_leads.professional_id as proId
  , professional_leads.id as proLeadId
  , professional_leads.user_id
  , professional_leads.interview_offered_at
  , professional_leads.sms_enabled
  , professional_leads.email_enabled
  , professional_leads.resume_pdf_object_key
  , professional_leads.created_at
  , professional_leads.updated_at
  , professional_leads.reschedule_count
  , professional_leads.experience_level
  , professional_leads.waitlisted_reason
  , professional_leads.resume_state
  , professional_leads.interview_state
  , professional_leads.state
  , professional_leads.profession_id
  , professional_leads.indicated_specialty_codes
  , professional_leads.other_specialties
  , professional_leads.professional_id
  , professional_leads.license_received_on
  , professional_leads.license_expires_on
  , professional_leads.region_id
  , professional_leads.marketing_channel
  , professional_leads.newsletter
  , professional_leads.referral_code
  , professional_leads.asset_proof_type
  , professional_leads.verification_state
  , professional_leads.duplicate
FROM
  professional_leads
WHERE
  id IN :clause
DEBUG 2022-10-01 21:25:45,346 [[MuleRuntime].uber.15: [api-database-sapi].Copy_of_get-Flow.BLOCKING @7f0aedd] [processor: Copy_of_get-Flow/processors/0/processors/0; event: 232aba80-41f1-11ed-b583-f02f4b10a50d] org.mule.db.commons.shaded.internal.domain.executor.AbstractExecutor: Executing query:
SELECT
  professional_leads.first_name
  , professional_leads.last_name
  , professional_leads.email
  , professional_leads.phone_number
  , professional_leads.professional_id as proId
  , professional_leads.id as proLeadId
  , professional_leads.user_id
  , professional_leads.interview_offered_at
  , professional_leads.sms_enabled
  , professional_leads.email_enabled
  , professional_leads.resume_pdf_object_key
  , professional_leads.created_at
  , professional_leads.updated_at
  , professional_leads.reschedule_count
  , professional_leads.experience_level
  , professional_leads.waitlisted_reason
  , professional_leads.resume_state
  , professional_leads.interview_state
  , professional_leads.state
  , professional_leads.profession_id
  , professional_leads.indicated_specialty_codes
  , professional_leads.other_specialties
  , professional_leads.professional_id
  , professional_leads.license_received_on
  , professional_leads.license_expires_on
  , professional_leads.region_id
  , professional_leads.marketing_channel
  , professional_leads.newsletter
  , professional_leads.referral_code
  , professional_leads.asset_proof_type
  , professional_leads.verification_state
  , professional_leads.duplicate
FROM
  professional_leads
WHERE
  id IN ?
Parameters:
clause = ('6a379873-93f9-4b16-8752-168aa92c8846','a234570e-a739-4bcc-847a-a875f5202398')
```

I flatten the array in a var `ids`:

`"(" ++ (attributes.queryParams.*id map "'$'" joinBy ",") ++ ")"`

I have my query as follows:

```
%dw 2.0
output text
---
"SELECT
  professional_leads.first_name
  , professional_leads.last_name
  , professional_leads.email
  , professional_leads.phone_number
  , professional_leads.professional_id as proId
  , professional_leads.id as proLeadId
  , professional_leads.user_id
  , professional_leads.interview_offered_at
  , professional_leads.sms_enabled
  , professional_leads.email_enabled
  , professional_leads.resume_pdf_object_key
  , professional_leads.created_at
  , professional_leads.updated_at
  , professional_leads.reschedule_count
  , professional_leads.experience_level
  , professional_leads.waitlisted_reason
  , professional_leads.resume_state
  , professional_leads.interview_state
  , professional_leads.state
  , professional_leads.profession_id
  , professional_leads.indicated_specialty_codes
  , professional_leads.other_specialties
  , professional_leads.professional_id
  , professional_leads.license_received_on
  , professional_leads.license_expires_on
  , professional_leads.region_id
  , professional_leads.marketing_channel
  , professional_leads.newsletter
  , professional_leads.referral_code
  , professional_leads.asset_proof_type
  , professional_leads.verification_state
  , professional_leads.duplicate
FROM
  professional_leads
WHERE
  id IN :clause"
```

My input parameters in the call is:

```
{
    "clause": vars.ids
}
```

Grabbing the query and using the bind variable verbatim, the query executes fine.

Is there a limitation with IN and bind variables?

Comment: What's the actual XML of the actual database operation? And versions of Mule and the connector?

Comment: `select * from books b where b.id in :clause`  And input `(1, 2)` for parameter `:clause` - this is working

Comment: That is not the same query from the original question and also it is not what I asked. If there is an issue with a database operation, you should share also the database connector operation snippet (ie the `<db:select ...>` in the flow). Not just the SQL part, nor just how you built the SQL query.